# Cakephp 3 How can i User manually activate?

Tags: cakephp, conditional-statements

I would like that the user is not activated after registering. The User must be activated by an admin.How do I do that in Cake 3?

The Code for the condition in Cake 2 was:

```
/AppController/

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('');
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'Form'=>array(
            'scope'=>array(
                'User.active'=>true
            )
        )
    );
    $this->set('logged_in',$this->Auth->loggedIn());
    $this->set('current_user',$this->Auth->user());

}
```

Comment: Citing the docs starts to become tedious again... **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#customizing-find-query**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CakePHP 3:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [                    
                'scope' => ['active' => '1']
            ]
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'home'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ]
    ]);
}
```